# Can i change the number of cells in collectionView based on the tableView Section iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have 2 arrays

```
var list3:Array< String > = Array < String >()
var list4:Array< String > = Array < String >()
```

I need to return the count of list 3 if the tableview Section is 0

and

I need to return the count of list 4 if the tableview Section is 4

How can i do this ?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch(section){
             case 0 : return list3.count
             case 1 : return list4.count
             default : return 0
          }
    }
```

it is not working...

Comment: Is the collectionView inside the TableViewCell?

Comment: yes ,it is inside a table view cell

Comment: what u are doing in `numberOfItemsInSection` is returning list3 items count if collectionView section is 0 and returning list4 items count if section is 1. Where is tableView here ? How is that associated with collectionView ? And what do u mean by not working? What is expected and what is happening?

Comment: i have a table view ... inside that ,i have 3 types of custom tavleView cells. among this...one table cell contains a collection view....what i need is load the table view cell with diff number of collectionview Cell

Comment: This is in obj-c but you can check out my github repo as well if you like: github.com/vnchopra/CustomCellTabledCollectionView

Answer (score 0):

In the overrided func of the UITableViewController when you create the UITableViewCell you will get from the indexPath the section and the row and you will set up your collection view inside the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
  let cell = ...
  if(indexPath.row == 3 && indexPath.section == 1){
     cell.numberOfCells = 123
   }
  }
```

Comment: how can i use this   numberOfCells value?

Comment: You will have a variable inside the tableViewCell class like var numberOfcells:Int? and when inside the collection of views delegate function you initialize the cells you will return numberOfcells ?? 0

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question and some of the comments and your answers, I understand is :

> you have a table view; in that table view one of the tableview cell (TVC) has a collection view. And based on whether this TVC is in section 0 or 1, you need yo decide number of elements that collection view.

You can achieve this by:

- Setting tag value of collection view to appropriate section number
  when you are creating the TVC.
- Then based on this tag, you can
  decide whether to populate the collection view using list3 or list4.
- If my understanding on your problem and suggested solution looks fine
  and you need code snippet, do let me know and I will add it. Thanks.

Comment: I added the sample project on GitHub - https://github.com/masture/CollectionViewInTableViewCell.git